# CSS Width doesn't match up in page

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` contained within a larger `div` as follows:

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content">
    Bunch of text ... omitted
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

The css corresponding to these two are as follows (slightly edited for length):

```
#content {
margin: 0;
padding: 15px;
width: 720px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
border-left: solid;
overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar {
margin: 0;
padding: 15px;
width: 198px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: white;
border-style: solid;
}

.content-container {
position: relative;
width: 978px;
height: 1060px;
}
```

I have [read](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) that the width attribute does not include padding. When I load the page up in Chrome and inspect the elements, `content` has a width of 705, instead of the expect 720. However, `sidebar` has the correct width of 198px. Does anyone have an explanation?

[image]

Comment: i got 720. can you check if there is other things overwriting it?
https://jsfiddle.net/5xdg4qmw/

Comment: Yes, it should give 720, I think the problem is exclusive to my page. But it's strange because chrome would usually show a slashed out line if the width is overwritten. Not sure where to check.

Comment: do you have it a a live site that i can check? thanks
or you could include all ur css in a fiddle

Comment: are you using box-sizing: border-box? I added that to your fiddle and got 720 px. without box sizing it said 753, 720 (width) + 30 (padding) + 3 (border)

Comment: Here's a fiddle with all my source code. I was toying around a bit and made width 717px, but the same problem remains. https://jsfiddle.net/ztfhkfp3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have an explanation?

It's because of the scrollbar (resulting from `overflow: auto`).

There are some cross-browser inconsistencies related to the scrollbar and how it is included in the width calculations. In Chrome and Safari, the width of the scrollbar isn't included in the content width, whereas in Firefox and IE, the width of the scrollbar *is* included in the content width.

In the jsFiddle example that you provided, you will notice that the content width is `717px` in Chrome after removing the scrollbar. With the scrollbar, `15px` will be subtracted from the content width (resulting in `702px`).

Answer (score 0):

try to clear any possible default margin or padding for the parent div:

```
.content-container {
  margin:0px; 
  padding:0px;
}
```